# Why is JSON_TABLE() joining inconsistent?

Tags: json, mysql-8.0

In MySQL 8, we can now use a JSON typed column and also use built-in functions like JSON_TABLE() but as I'm using in different scenarios sometimes I see results I did not expect.

> Docs for JSON_TABLE() : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html

Maybe JSON_TABLE is not the way to accomplish joining with a piece of JSON. There are some search functions MySQL provides, but nothing jumped out at me as an alternative to JSON_TABLE()

> Docs for JSON search functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
    NAME varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    METADATA JSON NULL
);

INSERT INTO USER VALUES
('John', '[1,3]'),
('Jane', '[2]'),
('Bob', null),
('Sally', '[9]');


CREATE TABLE ROLES (
  ID int NOT NULL,
  NAME varchar(64) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ROLES VALUES
(1, 'Originator'),
(2, 'Approver'),
(3, 'Reviewer');
```

---

**Query #1** - Why is Bob not returned?

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER,
JSON_TABLE(
      USER.METADATA, "$[*]" 
      COLUMNS(ID int PATH "$" NULL ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY)
) AS JSON_ROLE_LINK;

## Results ##
| NAME  | METADATA | ID  |
| ----- | -------- | --- |
| John  | [1, 3]   | 1   |
| John  | [1, 3]   | 3   |
| Jane  | [2]      | 2   |
| Sally | [9]      | 9   |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * FROM ROLES;

## Results ##
| ID  | NAME       |
| --- | ---------- |
| 1   | Originator |
| 2   | Approver   |
| 3   | Reviewer   |
```

---

**Query #3** - Why are there no results?

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER
JOIN ROLES ON ROLES.id IN (
    SELECT ID FROM JSON_TABLE(
      USER.METADATA, "$[*]" 
      COLUMNS(ID int PATH "$" NULL ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY)
    ) AS JSON_ROLE_LINK     
);

##There are no results to be displayed.
```

---

**Query #4** - Not JOINing with an IN() returns correct results.

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER,
JSON_TABLE(
      USER.METADATA, "$[*]" 
      COLUMNS(ID int PATH "$" NULL ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY)
) AS JSON_ROLE_LINK
JOIN ROLES ON ROLES.ID = JSON_ROLE_LINK.ID;

## Results ##
| NAME | METADATA | ID  | ID  | NAME       |
| ---- | -------- | --- | --- | ---------- |
| John | [1, 3]   | 1   | 1   | Originator |
| John | [1, 3]   | 3   | 3   | Reviewer   |
| Jane | [2]      | 2   | 2   | Approver   |
```

---

**Query #5** - Where is Bob?

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER,
JSON_TABLE(
      USER.METADATA, "$[*]" 
      COLUMNS(ID int PATH "$" NULL ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY)
) AS JSON_ROLE_LINK
LEFT JOIN ROLES ON ROLES.ID = JSON_ROLE_LINK.ID;

## Results ##
| NAME  | METADATA | ID  | ID  | NAME       |
| ----- | -------- | --- | --- | ---------- |
| John  | [1, 3]   | 1   | 1   | Originator |
| Jane  | [2]      | 2   | 2   | Approver   |
| John  | [1, 3]   | 3   | 3   | Reviewer   |
| Sally | [9]      | 9   |     |            |
```

---

**Query #6** - Why does a LEFT JOIN with IN() return the expected results when query #3 returned nothing?

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER
LEFT JOIN ROLES ON ROLES.id IN (
    SELECT ID FROM JSON_TABLE(
      USER.METADATA, "$[*]" 
      COLUMNS(ID int PATH "$" NULL ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY)
    ) AS JSON_ROLE_LINK     
);

## Results ##
| NAME  | METADATA | ID  | NAME       |
| ----- | -------- | --- | ---------- |
| John  | [1, 3]   | 1   | Originator |
| John  | [1, 3]   | 3   | Reviewer   |
| Jane  | [2]      | 2   | Approver   |
| Bob   |          |     |            |
| Sally | [9]      |     |            |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dAqQQFsi7wjjo3etqmfcSg/2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ISNULL` property to create dummy `json`

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER,
JSON_TABLE(
      IFNULL(USER.METADATA,'[0]'), "$[*]" 
      COLUMNS(ID int PATH "$" NULL ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY)
) AS JSON_ROLE_LINK;
```

[**DB FIDDLE**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/X3D5pfAj9Xdo9wbLHFvLL/0)

```
#1 No JOINS with JSON_TABLE where is Bob?
SELECT * 
FROM USER,
JSON_TABLE(
      IFNULL(USER.METADATA,'[0]'), "$[*]" 
      COLUMNS(ID int PATH "$" NULL ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY)
) AS JSON_ROLE_LINK;

#2 Verify our ROLE recrods exist
SELECT * FROM ROLES;

#3 Regular JOIN with JSON_TABLE inside the IN(), why are there no results?
SELECT * 
FROM USER
JOIN ROLES ON ROLES.id IN (
    SELECT ID FROM USER, JSON_TABLE(
      USER.METADATA, "$[*]" 
      COLUMNS(ID int PATH "$" NULL ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY)
    ) AS JSON_ROLE_LINK     
);

#4 Regular JOIN with JSON_TABLE, returns expected results
SELECT * 
FROM USER,
JSON_TABLE(
      IFNULL(USER.METADATA,'[0]'), "$[*]" 
      COLUMNS(ID int PATH "$" NULL ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY)
) AS JSON_ROLE_LINK
JOIN ROLES ON ROLES.ID = JSON_ROLE_LINK.ID;

#5 LEFT JOIN with JSON_TABLE, where is Bob?
SELECT * 
FROM USER,
JSON_TABLE(
      IFNULL(USER.METADATA,'[0]'), "$[*]" 
      COLUMNS(ID int PATH "$" NULL ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY)
) AS JSON_ROLE_LINK
LEFT JOIN ROLES ON ROLES.ID = JSON_ROLE_LINK.ID;

#6 LEFT JOIN with JSON_TABLE inside the IN(), returns expected results
SELECT * 
FROM USER
LEFT JOIN ROLES ON ROLES.id IN (
    SELECT ID FROM JSON_TABLE(
      IFNULL(USER.METADATA,'[0]'), "$[*]" 
      COLUMNS(ID int PATH "$" NULL ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY)
    ) AS JSON_ROLE_LINK     
);
```

Comment: Thanks, the `IFNULL` resolved issues for query #1 and #5. In query #3 you added the USER table inside the `IN()` which made the query start producing results, but it was returning *Bob* and *Sally* which it should not be. However, I was able to make it work with an additional *WHERE* clause. You can see in my updated fiddle. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j7m5xDfXQVbdtW7P6a3ekn/1). However, the last question that is a mystery in my initial fiddle are queries #3, and #6. The only difference between the two is the latter uses a *LEFT JOIN*, which has results, but the first does not.